# VS2012 javascript intellisense field description

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Is there a way to enable the field xml tag description for a property?  Example code:

```
function MyObj() {
    /// <field name='num' type='int'>integer field</field>
    this.num = 5;
}
```

Then if I do the following:

[image: image of intellisense]

I do not see the description "Integer field" I specified.

Is this a disabled option somewhere?  Or just a bug?  Documentation for javascript intellisense isn't very prevelent :(

Edit: It should be noted I have resharper installed.

Answer (score 1):

try something like :

```
  function getArea(radius)
  {
      /// <summary>Determines the area of a circle that has the specified radius parameter.</summary>
      /// <param name="radius" type="Number">The radius of the circle.</param>
      /// <returns type="Number">The area.</returns>
      var areaVal;
      areaVal = Math.PI * radius * radius;
      return areaVal;
  }
```

in your case:

```
function MyObj() {
     /// <field name='HorsePower' type='Number'>integer field</field>
    this.num = 5;
}
```

from [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514138.aspx)

if that is not working Use the IntelliSense page of the Options dialog box to add an extension as a reference group. You can access the IntelliSense page by choosing **Tools**, **Options** on the menu bar, and then choosing **Text Editor**, **JavaScript**, **IntelliSense**, **References**.

That is explained in [These MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874692.aspx)

Comment: Hi!  Thank you for your comment.  I just realized I have resharper intellisense on, and when I changed it to use Visual Studio default it appeared correctly.  Do you by chance know of a way to correct this with the resharper extension?

Comment: @SarahBourt - yea , http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Ultimate+Guide+to+Speeding+Up+ReSharper+(and+Visual+Studio)